# app crashing while fetching record from core data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, ios7, xcode5

Hi friends my app is crashed while fetch request is performed in core data.the below is the message showing while crash.

"2014-10-07 14:38:07.203 Social[1540:60b] -[AppDelegate fetchAllAds]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9725da0
2014-10-07 14:38:07.209 Social[1540:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', **reason: '-[AppDelegate fetchAllAds]:** unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9725da0'
*** First throw call stack:

```
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x025201e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01e1e8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x025bd243 -[NSObject(NSObject)  
doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0251050b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x025100ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   Social                              0x00002e5b -[ShoppingCartViewController viewDidLoad] +  
139
6   UIKit                               0x00bfd33d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
7   UIKit                               0x00bfd5d9 -[UIViewController view] + 35
8   UIKit                               0x00c0cf89 -[UIViewController shouldAutorotate] + 36
9   UIKit                               0x00c0d2d1 -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentationInWindow:fromInterfaceOrientation:] + 297
10  UIKit                               0x00eab3d5 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:] + 2330
11  UIKit                               0x00c095d5 -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 6538
12  UIKit                               0x00c09aef -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 130
13  UIKit                               0x00c09b2f -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] + 56
14  UIKit                               0x01053e00 -[UIStoryboardModalSegue perform] + 271
15  UIKit                               0x01042f0c -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 174
16  UIKit                               0x01042f87 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
17  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01e30880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
18  UIKit                               0x00ae03b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
19  UIKit                               0x00ae0345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
20  UIKit                               0x00be1bd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
21  UIKit                               0x00be1fc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
22  UIKit                               0x00be1243 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
23  UIKit                               0x00b1fddd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
24  UIKit                               0x00b209d1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117
25  UIKit                               0x00af25f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
26  UIKit                               0x00adc353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
27  CoreFoundation                      0x024a977f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
28  CoreFoundation                      0x024a910b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
29  CoreFoundation                      0x024c61ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
30  CoreFoundation                      0x024c59d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
31  CoreFoundation                      0x024c57eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
32  GraphicsServices                    0x03ca25ee GSEventRunModal + 192
33  GraphicsServices                    0x03ca242b GSEventRun + 104
34  UIKit                               0x00adef9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
35  Social                              0x00017a2d main + 141
36  libdyld.dylib                       0x0393b701 start + 1
37  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
```

)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

The below is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    DBManager* manager = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    self.fetchedRecordsArray = [manager fetchAllAds];
    [self.shoppingtbl reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.fetchedRecordsArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
    *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ShoppingCart";
    ShoppingCart *cell = (ShoppingCart*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier 
    forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Ad * record = [self.fetchedRecordsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.addesc.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",record.data];
    return cell;
}
```

Note i have retired all the core data functions in separate file called dbmanager.

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you that the `AppDelegate` doesn't have the function `fetchAllAds`.

Just as a quick note. It **shouldn't** have that function anyway.

Something is missing (or mis-typed) in the app delegate. If you can't fix it from this then you need to show the code in your app delegate.

**EDIT**

Oh! I just realised. You have a class called `DBManager` but the way you are loading it...

```
DBManager* manager = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

Is actually putting the `UIAppDelegate` into the property.

You need something like...

```
DBManager *manager = [[DBManager alloc] init];
```

This will stop the error.

What this is doing...

When you run `[manager fetchAllAds];` it is getting the property `manager`.

This is a reference to the App Delegate because of how you're loading it.

**EDIT 1**

OK, it sounds like maybe your DBManager is a property of your app delegate.

Then you can load it like this...

```
DBManager *manager = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].dbManager; //or whatever the property is.
```

Comment: in my code i am not specifying [appdelegate fetch ads]...but is showing what can i do.

Comment: @user3354840 yeah, but you have `DBManager *manager` and into that you are putting the `app delegate`. Then when you try to run `fetchAllAds` it doesn't exist. You need to create the `DBManager` and put it into the `manager` property.

Comment: right now the application is working...but all the fields are showing null..what can i do..but the datas are saved in db.

Comment: @user3354840 if that doesn't work then I don't know without looking at more code.

Answer (score 0):

Friend this is not the problem of coreData but you are accessing the wrong object at viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
DBManager* manager = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
self.fetchedRecordsArray = [manager fetchAllAds];
[self.shoppingtbl reloadData];
}
```

Here your code `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;` will return the object of `appDelegate` not `DBManager` and you are storing it in your DBManager which is wrong. so access `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] dbManager]` in this way if you have a property dbManager in your appDelegate.

So if you have a property of DBManager in your app access it in such a way

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    DBManager* manager = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] dbManager];
    self.fetchedRecordsArray = [manager fetchAllAds];
    [self.shoppingtbl reloadData];
    }
```

or create a new object here

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    DBManager* manager = [[DBManager alloc] init];
    self.fetchedRecordsArray = [manager fetchAllAds];
    [self.shoppingtbl reloadData];
    }
```

Comment: I right now its working thanks..but all the fields are showing null..what can i do..

Comment: @user3354840 so have you made a new object or accessing the property from appDelegate?

Comment: If you are creating a new class object then you should also create new managedObject context and create a new fetch request either inside your fetchAllAds method or viewDidLoad of your DBManager class. only then it will work.

Comment: ok if call DBManager* manager = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] dbManager]; method.then it will work?

Comment: @user3354840 Brother the simple thing is this, that access the object of DBManager from any where in project but it should have a valid NSManagedObjectContext object and NSFetchRequest object to access the data from coreData.